# safari protractor - switch to iframe

Tags: protractor

I have code like this

```
     await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(await this.iFrameLightbox), 20000);
     if (await this.iFrameLightbox.isDisplayed()) {
        await browser.switchTo().frame(iFrame.getWebElement());
     }
```

When I print the isDisplayed() value, it prints "true". But then fails to switch to the iframe in safari with this error:

`Failed: A request to switch to a frame could not be satisfied because the frame could not be found.`

The same code works correctly in chrome. Sometimes, it even does some actions inside the iFrame and then fails with this error in safari.

Can someone help to resolve this issue

Comment: This seems to be a known issue with Safari. There is a work around mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/webdriver/Wv2gEtln2jc/n7Vm1uYx1DMJ) but written in Java. You may be able to adapt it to your code

Comment: it is very flaky. It passes sometimes and sometimes errors out. I tried adding a sleep ..a long sleep - still the flakiness persists